# SwiftUI: align HStack in VStack relative center of a HStack's subview?

Tags: swiftui

So I have this view:

```
struct AlignmentTest: View {
    
    @State var op:Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.green)
                    .opacity(op)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width:150, height: 50)
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

It draws this:

[image]

Given one of the comments I making this edit:

Question:

How can I get the red rectangle to be centered (Horizontally) in the VStack and have the green circle to stick to the left edge of the red rectangle?

Is there to do it without hardcoding numbers? Maybe with alignment guides?

Comment: "Is there to do it without hardcoding numbers?" -- You already have numbers hardcoded into the widths of the circle and rectangle. Are you thinking you might have something dynamically sized in there? I can update my answer to use a `GeometryReader` so nothing is hardcoded if necessary, but if you plan to already have the child elements hardcoded size-wise, it seems like you may as well hard code the alignment.

Comment: I am planning to probably applying scale animation to the circle.... and, in general, I was trying to figure out how to get this one without numbers, so, alignment guides if possible. Seems like the cleanest way to me. Anyway, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: Okay. I've updated my answer -- its a little contrived right now because the frames are explicitly set, but it'll behave the same with dynamic content as well.

Comment: But why once you ask the question with hard code values then change the goal to other thing? We put time for this question right?  @zumzum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to get the circle to stick to the rectangle's edge, explicitly declare a `spacing` of `0` on the `HStack`.
2. Since you wanted no hard-coded numbers, I used PreferenceKeys to transmit the width values up to the parent.

Note that I'm not using `offset` because that can affect user interaction of child elements (since the system believes they're placed differently).

*(I added the background and border to easily visually see the centering -- these could obviously be removed)*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var op:Double = 1
    @State private var rectangleWidth : CGFloat = 0
    @State private var circleWidth : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.black
                Color.white
            }
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.green)
                        .opacity(op)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                            Color.clear.preference(key: CircleWidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
                        })
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(width:150, height: 50)
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                            Color.clear.preference(key: RectangleWidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
                        })
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(RectangleWidthPreferenceKey.self) { pref in
                    self.rectangleWidth = pref
                 }
                .onPreferenceChange(CircleWidthPreferenceKey.self) { pref in
                    self.circleWidth = pref
                 }
                .border(Color.blue)
                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { d in
                    circleWidth + rectangleWidth / 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleWidthPreferenceKey : PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct RectangleWidthPreferenceKey : PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way for you:

```
struct AlignmentTest: View {
    
    @State var op:Double = 1
    
    private let rectangleSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 50.0)
    private let circleSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    private let padding: CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {

                    
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: rectangleSize.width, height: rectangleSize.height)
                    .overlay(
                    
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.green)
                            .opacity(op)
                            .frame(width: circleSize.width, height: circleSize.height)
                            .offset(x: -(rectangleSize.width + circleSize.width)/2.0 - padding)
                    
                    
                    )
            }
            
            
        }
    }

}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could put something the same width as the circle to the right of the rectangle:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Circle()
            .fill(.green)
            .opacity(op)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width:150, height: 50)
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 0)
        
    }
}
```